# Upload grouped files in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I got a small question, which would help me improve my work-flow big time :)

I am using PHPStorm to build all my HTML/PHP/JS/CSS related project. One cool feature are the filewatchers you can setup for e.g. closure. Everything is working fine and as expected, but one thing bothers me: If you compile a js-file with closure, the compiled file will be grouped with the original file in the project list, which is quite handy. But if you upload your files directly to your testing system with PHPStorm (either via the context menu, or with a keyboard shortcut) it "only" uploads" the original file. Does anyone know, which setting I have to change, to upload everything together ?

Comment: There is no such setting: Deployment plugin does know nothing about file watcher and how it groups generated files. You have to explicitly upload such files.

Answer (score 0):

> grouped with the original file in the project list

Unless I'm not understanding correctly this should mean it's saved in the same base path as the original file.  So long as you have deployment correctly configured

- You have a default deployment server selected.
- "Upload changed files automatically to the default server" == "Always|On explicit save..."
- "Upload external changes" IS checked

Then your newly created files should be deployed automatically (immediately or on save, based on above configuration).

If my above assumption is incorrect and instead the generated file is stored in a separate folder then you want to have your file watcher refresh the directory by specifying which "Output paths to refresh".  After your file watcher completes it should refresh the output path(s) you have specified, at which point PhpStorm should then recognize the changed/created file and deploy it to your default server (either immediately or on your next save action based on your deployment configuration).

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the Scopes feature. 
In the Inspections settings it's also possible to add the scopes and enable/disable each inspection per scope.